# Tymon/jwt-auth 1.0.0-rc1 in laravel 5.5, can't refresh when ttl is expired but refresh_ttl is not

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, jwt

I have this weird problem with the `tymon/jwt-auth:1.0.0-rc1` package in Laravel 5.5.

I have installed the package and followed the instructions on how to configure the defaults (from this link: http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/laravel-installation), the only thing I have changed outside of that is that I have set `JWT_TTL=1` (for testing purposes) in my `.env` file, the `JWT_REFRESH_TTL` is still the default value (2 weeks).

Now I can generate a token when I send my credentials, I can also refresh the tokens when the `JWT_TTL` is not expired but when I try to refresh the token when the `JWT_TTL` is expired but the `JWT_REFRESH_TTL` is not, I get a `401: Unauthenticated.` response..

Is this normal behavior? If so, why is there a `JWT_REFRESH_TTL` in the first place?

Is there any way to fix this or do I just not understand this right?

Thanks in advance! :)

**Edit:**

I have made some progress, although I don't really know if it is the proper way to do it..

In the docs for `1.0.0-rc1`:

`$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);`

So the refresh route is protected, but ofcourse it doesn't get through the auth middleware when the token is expired, so I added the refresh route like this:

`$this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login', 'refresh']]);`

I don't know if this has negative side effects or maybe they have forgotten to add it in the docs?

Comment: where did you add the except line for auth?Am using dingo api as well and have set it as $api->group(['middleware' => 'api.auth'], ['except' => ['login', 'refresh']], function ($api) {

                $api->post('refresh', 'App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController@refresh');

        }); Still it doesnt refresh

Comment: I got it now I just needed to not include refresh token within the auth protected routes